# Smooth JQuery animations for three-column menu with fullscreen expanding div boxes?

Tags: jquery, html, fullscreen, expand, smoothing

For a fullscreen three-column menu I've created three absolute-positioned div boxes and made each of them expand horizontally fullscreen with a JQuery selector and the toggle command. It works, but I'd like to have the animation smoothly. How could I do that?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kplasa/tSk3Z/4/) code for it.

This is the HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id='controls' style="background-color: green;" onclick="fullscreen();">
    </div>
    <div id='controls_002' style="background-color: yellow;" onclick="fullscreen_002();">
    </div>
    <div id='controls_003' style="background-color: purple;" onclick="fullscreen_003();">
    </div>
```

This is the JQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper div').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().not(this).toggleClass('hide');
});
});
```

And this is the CSS code:

```
    .wrapper{
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.blue{
    width: 33.33333333%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: blue;
}

.red{
    width: 33.33333333%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
}

.green{
    width: 33.33333333%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: green;
} 

div{
    float: left;
}


.active{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.hide{
    display: none;
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or with a simple jQuery code with no changes to your fiddle css code
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/2rxRx/1/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper div').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('go')
        if($(this).hasClass('go')){
          $(this).animate({'width':'100%'},{
              duration:1000,
              step:function(gox){
                  var width = gox < 100 ? (100 - gox) / 2 : 0;
                  $(this).siblings().css('width', width + "%"); 
                  }
              })
        }else{
            $('.wrapper div').animate({'width':'33.33%'},1000)
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution fittest the most of how the three panels should behave in my website design.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add CSS transitions to the divs, unless you really need support for old browsers.

```
.wrapper div {
   -webkit-transition: all 1s;
   transition: all 1s;
}
```

I also added absolute positions to the divs, because the float seems to trigger some glitchy animations. Last but not least, put the 'active' div at top with z-index

http://jsfiddle.net/tSk3Z/10/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll save your solution for my next tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS solution is probably the best way but if you are still looking for the jquery solution you could use the [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method with the step-function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper div').click(function() {
        var obj = $(this),
            siblings = obj.siblings();
        obj.animate(
            {width: "100%"}, 
            {
                duration: 5000,
                step: function(now){
                    var width = now < 100 ? (100 - now) / 2 : 0;
                    siblings.css('width', width + "%");                    
                }
            }
        );
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tSk3Z/11/

You may need to adjust the duration value to your needs

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution was very helpful, too.